# Nativescript microphone access

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I ma searching for a solution to rekord microphone audio and send it into backend. This aplication is building on Nativescript environment for Android and iOS. I tried nativescript-audio but I have problem with run example (repported issue}. Does Nativescript has solution like this? Someone has working example of nativescript-audio or some alternative?

I try to use TNSPlayer and it still appears. Issue [link](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio/issues/26)

`file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/./bundles/core.umd.js:1091:24: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NSErrorWrapper: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)`

Maybe I am doing sth wrong.

Comment: The audio plugin should work just fine. I've used it in a couple production applications as many others. So you might need to add more info on how you're using it. What platform (android/iOS/both)? The code you're using trying to record audio. Simulator or real device. With some more info finding a solution shouldn't be too difficult :)

Comment: Okay I see you posted on the issue :) my fault for not checking. I won't have time to do into this until next week most likely but I do know the plugin works as it's in many production apps so something isn't right of course but we can find the issue. I might need a sample to try running if you can put together a demo app repo with the issue or send me a zip of an app that does this

Comment: Thank U @BradMartin for response. Today I will try to run demo. I try to run it on ios emulator iphone 5se 10.3. All in all this application will be running on both ios + android (as I expect this is the main power of nativescript). I will come back to you with info after run demo from your repo.

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski any progress with your issue?